# picture from datagridview to picturebox

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a winform app in c# with a `datagridview` witch gets it´s values from an `sql` database, but when i click one line from de `datagridview` the data gets displayed in textboxes to be edited.
THe problem is that one of the columns that can be edited is an image. 
I can upload the image and see it in the datagrid but when i clic the rowheader to select i get an error:"String of input characters with incorrect format"
The code is:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    desc2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    tipo.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    prumos.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();  
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: On which exact line do you get the exception? It seems to be related to the `Convert.ToInt32` more than the image...

Comment: @OfirWinegarten unfortunately the system does not throw an exception.
I only get the error, the form closes and i get sent back to the previous form.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten i tried to comment the convert line and now i get the error: Impossible to associate the object of type System.string to System.byte

Comment: Good, so first add a try catch to your `dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick`. Obviously, you have few issues here. What are the type of the different columns?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten the type of columns are all text except for the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue comes from the `Convert.ToInt32` and has nothing to do with Image. Be sure that the text contains a number only.

The second issue with the Image can be done like this:

```
var imageCell = (DataGridViewImageCell)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2];
pictureBox1.Image = (Image)imageCell.Value;
```

**UPDATE - The above is wrong**

The issue is wrong indices, like written in the comments:
The correct code is:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value‌​); 
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but i get an error at line :
 pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream((Image)imageCell.Value);
cannot convert from ´system.drawings.image to system.IO.stream

Comment: Grrr still get the same error :\
Ill upload a screenshot from the form, maybe it´s another reason

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: still String of input characters with incorrect format

Comment: For me it looks like you are trying the wrong field index. from the snapshot it looks like the image is in index 0 not 2. and your int is index 3 not 1

Comment: ok, so i tried your index now i get a diferent error: Impossible to associate object type system.byte to system.drawing.image

Comment: Ok, my answer is wrong. try now with the memory stream as you did before but with the correct index: `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the index. try the `first(id)` cell 0.

```cs
ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```